# Is it possible to add static kernel drivers to the Linux kernel of a distribution?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, android-source

I may have a couple assumptions of Linux incorrect about the Linux system, and for that I apologize.

I have been educating myself on the Android and Linux systems for a while now and I started looking into installing a custom boot loader and Linux system onto an older Samsung tablet. Immediately upon looking into the feasibility of this, most of the answers I could find were that it wasn't possible because you would need the drivers that are being used by the android kernel to communicate with the OEM hardware in whatever Linux kernel you are installing.

I have one of these tablets rooted and I believe I may have found the drivers I need (not sure on that yet), and so I guess my question is, is it possible to take the drivers and put them into a Linux kernel within a distribution install image and install Linux on the device (using also a custom boot loader)?

I presume because someone hasn't done this before there is a pretty good reason why, but I am basically looking to be able to use Linux on my old tablet without the resources being taken from Android, and personally in my opinion, if I don't need Android and can install Linux straight on to the machine, then why keep it?

In the long run I am looking into LFS to create a custom distribution that can be installed on these tablets, but the most important question to me right now is if I do create this distribution can I get the drivers that the hardware needs (and even then will my kernel be able to use them?).

I also understand that some of these drivers may be proprietary drivers provided by the manufacturer, but I am not looking to profit off of this but instead research the feasibility of a better personal on-the-go computing setup.

I may be terribly wrong on how I may have described some things, so here are some of my assumptions:

- The .ko files in the Android /lib/modules/ directory are the static kernel drivers I am looking for for that device.
- The drivers aren't written for specifically the Android system, but for all Linux variants and would be compatible with another distribution.
- If the drivers were written for the Android system, then one would be able to edit or modify those drivers to work with a different distribution.
- One could "put the drivers into an installation image", or if not, then one would have to compile the kernel from source with those static drivers.

**TL:DR, If this all just amounts to rambling, here are my specific questions:**

- Is it possible to copy the static kernel drivers of a rooted Android device to something like the SDcard?
- Is it then possible to "put" or "compile" those same static drivers into a Linux distribution before installing it onto said tablet using something like Odin, or the like?

Comment: This seems like an `AOSP` related question, you can add this tag to your question.

Comment: Because vendors doesn't care about the freedom of their users, they do not upstream the necessary drivers (the best position is with x86 hardware, followed by only few ARM platforms). You **may not** simple use drivers like that. And the best approach is to see what has been done in OSes like Lineage or Sailfish.